# Value below 0 Change program

Tags: java, android

If there is any way to change program when the "a" is below 0

I mean when the A is larger than 0 that the program will be like this and when below 0 than the program will be like B-A

```
private Button Button;
private EditText Num1;
private EditText Num2;
private EditText Num3;
private EditText Num4;
private EditText Num5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zisk);

    Button = findViewById(R.id.btnBtn);
    Num1 = findViewById(R.id.etNum1);
    Num2 = findViewById(R.id.etNum2);
    Num3 = findViewById(R.id.etNum3);
    Num4 = findViewById(R.id.etNum4);
    Num5 = findViewById(R.id.etNum5);

    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double  a,b,c,d,e;
            a = Double.parseDouble(Num1.getText() . toString());
            b = Double.parseDouble(Num2.getText() . toString());
            d = b-a;
            e = d*0.80;
            c = e*0.79;

            Num3.setText(Double.toString(c));
            Num4.setText(Double.toString(d));
            Num5.setText(Double.toString(e));

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with an if-statement, like `if (a < 0)`?

Comment: What do you mean, it's a simple if condition, `if (a < 0.0)`. What exactly are you asking about?